# Network emulation with Chrome DevTools

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm currently using version 4.0.0-alpha5 of the Selenium Webdriver NuGet package.
So this code only works when the DevTools are open in Chrome Version 98, but I don't understand why. As far as I know, should this always work, but the only thing that always works is the offline state.

```
devTools = driver as IDevTools;
session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings command = new EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings();

command.Latency = latencyInMilliseconds;
command.DownloadThroughput = downloadLimitKbps * 1024; // Kilobytes to bytes per second
command.UploadThroughput = uploadLimitKbps * 1024; // Kilobytes to bytes per second
command.Offline = false;

session.Network.EmulateNetworkConditions(command);
//session.SendCommand(command);
```

You will also find this code on [this site](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-4-overview/), so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Maybe this is a bug.

A solution would be to just open the DevTools during the test, but pressing a hotkey with selenium like F12 or any other Devtools hotkey doesn't work for me.
I tried it with Actions and also with sending keys on an object like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132704/pressing-f12-key-directly-through-selenium).

Another solution would maybe be to directly execute a CDP command, but I only found [examples in Java](https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-chrome-devtools-protocol-cdp-how-does-it-work/) and didn't find out how to do this. This is how you do it in Java:

```
driver.executeCdpCommand(commandString);
```

Thank you for reading, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I forgot to add the Network.Enable command, so don't forget to call it before you do the other stuff. This is the code I use now, without being version specific. (works until Selenium 4.0 alpha 5)

```
public void LimitNetwork(int latencyInMilliseconds, long downloadLimitMbps, long uploadLimitMbps)
{
    IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
    session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
    session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());

    EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings command = new EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings();

    command.Latency = latencyInMilliseconds;
    command.DownloadThroughput = downloadLimitMbps * 125000; // Mbps to bytes per second
    command.UploadThroughput = uploadLimitMbps * 125000; // Mbps to bytes per second
    command.Offline = false;

    session.Network.EmulateNetworkConditions(command);
}
```

If session.Network.EmulateNetworkConditions doesn't work you can also try session.SendCommand(command);

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 4.10.0
Chrome 114

```
        var devTools = driver as IDevTools;

        var session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();

        session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();

        session.SendCommand(new EmulateNetworkConditionsCommandSettings()
        {
            Offline = false,
            UploadThroughput = 500 * 1024 / 8, // 500 Kbps
            ConnectionType = ConnectionType.Cellular3g
        });
```

Needed usings:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Network;
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you.
I am new to Selenium/Chrome.  Why do we have to specify a specific version number in the using statements, such as V114?

Comment: @Sabuncu this same question doesn't allow me to sleep at night:) I screem WHYYYYY????

Comment: :) Since posting my comment above, I learned about the BiDi API.  Maybe that'll fix things.

Comment: @Sabuncu would you like to tell more?

Comment: Here's the page that warns about using devtools, and recommends using BiDi instead:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ChromeNetworkConditionsContext : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ChromeDriver _chromeDriver;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ChromeNetworkConditionsContext(ChromeDriver chromeDriver, ILogger logger)
        {
            _chromeDriver = chromeDriver;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _logger.Information("Resetting network conditions");
            _chromeDriver.NetworkConditions = new();
        }
    }

        public IDisposable SetRequestsLatency(TimeSpan latency)
        {
            _log.Information($"Enabling {latency} requests latency");
            var driver = _driverProvider.GetDriver();
            if (driver is ChromeDriver chromeDriver)
            {
                chromeDriver.NetworkConditions = new()
                {
                    Latency = latency
                };
                return new ChromeNetworkConditionsContext(chromeDriver, _log);
            }

            throw new WebDriverException($"NetworkConditions is not handled for {driver.GetType().Name}");
        }
```

That works for me. It adds a delay before each API call from UI.

Chrome version 99.

`<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.1.0" />`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, I found my mistake. :)