# Python Selenium function keys aren't working (F5 or F12)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get a selenium opened webpage to use function keys, however they don't seem to do anything.
Current code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.F12)
```

There isn't an error after running it. It's just that nothing happens.
Am I perhaps missing something? I am very confused.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem hasn't been solved yet.
but there are some suggested solutions to go around this,
Check this post:
[Pressing "F12" key directly through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132704/pressing-f12-key-directly-through-selenium)

Comment: Thank you, this lead me to another stack overflow where I found pyautogui. That did the trick for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: FYI for anyone else.

>import pyautogui
>pyautogui.press('f12')

Answer (score -1):

send_keys does not return anything hence you have to remove search.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.F12)
```

Comment: Even though `send_keys` returns `None` method should still be executed in a moment of `search` definition

Comment: I tried removing search, but it had the same result. The search function in there was from other testing.